# Typescript losing information on module load w/ no .dts file

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I'm having an issue where I'm either getting an error or losing type information when using Typescript instead of JavaScript.  The below "JS" code using VS Code actually gives me information about the `bitcore` variable being imported.  However when using Typescript, the imported `bitcore` variable gives an error saying it's lacking a definition file, and if I use the `var` instead of `import` to bring in the module, then I just get an "any" typed variable.

Given that this is Typescript, I should be able to get at least as much type information that Javascript can.

Edit: I've discovered a confusing, hidden "feature" of TS/Code where if no tsconfig.json is present, and the type is coming in as "any", and that type info is found legitimately in another open file in the VS Code workspace, in this case a javascript file, then it will "cache" that type info in the VS Code workspace and display it in the .ts file, even though TS is not getting that information itself.

TS

```
import bitcore = require("bitcore-lib")
var key = new bitcore.PrivateKey("testnet")
console.log(key)
```

[image]

JS

```
var bitcore = require("bitcore-lib");
var key = new bitcore.PrivateKey("testnet");
console.log(key);
```

[image]

TS w/ no tsconfig.json present and type info has been retrieved from "cache" after opening a different javascript file that has retrieved the type information.

[image]

Comment: Shouldn't your TS import statement read something like `import bitcore from "bitcore-lib"` ?

Comment: it still gives the same error regarding no declaration file

Answer (score 0):

In order for TypeScript to "know" your library you will need to supply a definition file for this library.
In many cases you could find the definition file for a library (popular ones) at [DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped).
There is an [open issue](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/6753) to create such file for this library, so you will have to wait or contribute to this repository.

Comment: Seems bizarre that if no definition file is present, then Typescript would actually LOSE type information compared to JavaScript

Comment: what do you mean compared to JavaScript?

Comment: updated w/ screenshots to show how when a tsconfig.json is present, TS actually has less type information than JS.